# where to find ipa file after npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release and successfully running on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, ipa

I followed the instructions on this link about Building your app for production:
http://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

AFter running the following commands:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

It Built successfully and now it is running on the Simulator

However I don't know where to find the ipa file.  Where can I find and get the ipa file after running the above command???